# Rails 4.0.2 ActionController::ParameterMissing in AuctionsController#create param not found:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actioncontroller

I am creating an auction website and I get an error when I run a command to create a new auction.

The model is simple:
class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :bets
has_many :profiles, :through => :bets

and etc.

The controller: `

> class AuctionsController < ApplicationController
>
> def **new**
> @auction = Auction.new
> end
>
> def **create**
>
> @auction = Auction.new(auction_params)
>
> if @auction.save
>
> ```
>  redirect_to(:action => 'index')
> ```
>
> else
>
> ```
>  render('new')
> ```
>
> end
>
> end
>
> **private**
>
> def auction_params
>
> ```
>  params.require(:auction_email).permit(:auction_description, :auction_location, :auction_deadline, :auction_title, bets_attributes: [ :bet_size], )
> ```
>
> end
> end

The new.html.erb has form in this way:

```
<%= form_for(:auction, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field(:auction_title) %>
```

and so on for every entry.

The error message is:

ActionController::ParameterMissing in AuctionsController#create param not found: auction_email

I have been trying to solve it with "if params[:status]", but it returns an empty form and database remains empty.

Rails version 4.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
def auction_params    
 params.require(:auction).permit(:auction_email,:auction_description, :auction_location, :auction_deadline, :auction_title, bets_attributes: [ :bet_size], )
end
```

Assuming that `Auction` is your model. 
`params.require` argument should be `:auction`(:modelname) and in `permit` method you pass the atrributes like `:auction_email`(:attributename) that you would like to insert/update in database.